# Reverse control-code look up for terminals

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, escape-characters

My understanding is that terminals often use ANSI control-codes to represent non-alphanumeric character sequences. For example, when editing `.inputrc` for Bash in Linux, it's easy to find code sequences that look as follows:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
```

The commands above [define](https://superuser.com/questions/269464/understanding-control-characters-in-inputrc) key bindings for the Bash commands `history-search-backward`, etc..

Now, in bash, I can use `read` to see how characters typed in my keyboard are mapped to ANSI control codes. E.g. For example, if I run `read`, and then enter `Ctrl-P`, I get: `^P`. Similarly, if I enter  `Alt-W`, I get: `^[W`.

My question is: Is there a program, tool or website that does the opposite? I.e. a tool that outputs or shows the sequence of keyboard keys that I need to type on my keyboard to obtain a given ANSI control-code sequence. For example, entering `^[W` should output: `Alt-W`

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`infocmp` can help.  It writes escape as `\E` rather than `\e` or `^[`.

For example, to find `\e[A`, which is your history-search-backward:

```
$ infocmp -1x | grep -F '=\E[A,'
       cuu1=\E[A,
$ man 5 terminfo | grep '  cuu1  '
       cursor_up                     cuu1       up       up one line
```

Which tells you to press cursor up, a.k.a. up arrow.

Note that you will need the `-x` flag (shown above) to display some combinations, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><-</kbd>.

These extended keys are not part of the standard, so they aren't listed in the terminfo man page, but they are documented in the [terminfo file](http://opensource.apple.com/source/X11apps/X11apps-30/xterm/xterm-243/terminfo).

Also note that the control sequences vary depending on which terminal you use.

You can get information about a different terminal by using `infocmp -1x <terminal>`, e.g. `infocmp -1x rxvt`, `infocmp -1x putty`, etc.

Once you figure out which one terminfo thinks you have, things will be easier if you set your `TERM` variable to match.

Comment: `infocmp` won't help if you use a combination not in the terminal description.

Answer (score 1):

The `cat` function is the usual way to do this, since you can use it to show what your keyboard actually sends.  bash doesn't use any of the extended information in the terminal database (it uses a **subset** of the conventional termcap capabilities).

The drawback to using `cat`, of course, is determining whether

```
^[[A
```

is <kbd>`^`</kbd><kbd>`[`</kbd><kbd>`A`</kbd> *or* <kbd>*escape*</kbd><kbd>`A`</kbd> (noting that bash provides a printable `\e` to represent the <kbd>*escape*</kbd> character).

In practice, you can ignore the former: essentially no one sends the three literal characters, "everyone" send that `^[` as the <kbd>*escape*</kbd> character).

Further reading:

- [How can I see what my keyboard sends?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#visible_keys) (ncurses FAQ)
- [unmap](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:unmap) (a program which does translate <kbd>*escape*</kbd> to `\E`).